# Gitlab: How to use/switch the group runners which are much availability

Tags: python, gitlab

I have below three runners available for my project

How can I utilize these three runners

```
1) runner1(abacd232323)
instance-abcfdd-.....
2)1) runner2(aba22211111)
instance-abasasddasd-....
3)runner3(dfdsffdfdg324324)
instance-.....
```

I have simple below gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:          # Runs First - Anything that needs to run prior to your scripts running
  - deploy
  - Script

variables:
  Domain:
    value: "dom"
  HOST_NAME:
    value: ""  
  JAVA_FILES_WITH_ARGS:
    value: ""

Run Python:
  stage: deploy
  script:  (./script.sh Git=True Cron=False Detail=NA)
```

I want this if runner is fully occupied then it can switch to the other runner which is free

Or let say 2jobs simultaneously using one runner then my job should use other runner which is completely free.
How can I achieve this

Comment: Are the runners showing as available within the CI/CD settings are of the project? If so, are they set to only run on tagged pipelines?

Comment: What do you mean by "use all"? -- what is the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Actually one runner use per job can I use another runner which has much availablity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have 3 registered runners, and you want to use the runner that is available regardless of which machine it's running on.

The proper way to do this is to have all 3 runners listen for the same `tag`. Runners can listen for multiple `tag` values; when you register the runner you pass in a comma separated list of tags for a runner to listen to. So your setup could look something like this:

```yaml
runner1:
  tags:
    - "my-runner"
    - "runner1"
runner2:
  tags:
    - "my-runner"
    - "runner2"
runner3:
  tags:
    - "my-runner"
    - "runner3"
```

Then if you want something to use whichever runner is available, you specify the `my-runner` tag, which all 3 runners are listening to. If you have something that's only installed on runner2, and thus that instance must be used, then you specify the `runner2` tag and it will wait for that runner to be available. Not that the runners don't prioritize tags, so runner2 will not prioritize jobs that only it can run over jobs that any other runners can run.

Alternatively, you can look at using autoscaling runners instead, which would solve your capacity problems by just spinning up additional runners machine if/when you run out of capacity (assume you're in the cloud, and can do something like this more easily).